# MarkLogic Data Hub - Quick Start UI not coming up

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I want to setup the Data Hub on my Linux machine.

- I use the Quick start version : `quick-start-4.3.1.war`
- Java JDK :  `1.8.0_161`

When I run the following command in the Linux terminal:

```
java - jar quick-start-4.3.1.war
```

I receive

> QuickStart UI is Ready and Listening on port 8080.

But when I try to access `http://localhost:8080` , it just shows me the Tomcat page but not the MarkLogic Quick Start UI.

I want to see the Data Hub Quick start UI instead of the Tomcat page.

Comment: Can you provide any other information about the problem?  Have you checked to see if the program is running or if there is any log output you can add to the question?

Answer (score 0):

My friend faced similar issue while using virtual machine. I am assuming that you are using same virtual machine (provided in fundamentals course). Can you try out with vm download available for data integration course. It works there.